# What is the meaning of multiple --include/--exclude flags in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

If I say `hg show $REV some_path -I're:.*included' -X're:.*excluded'`, what exactly does this mean? How does `some_path` interact with the `--include` pattern? How about the `--exclude` pattern?

Answer (score 3):

File matching is done with respect to three defined sets: the matches (`some_path`), the includes (`re:.*included`) and the excludes (`re:.*excluded`).  The set of finally matched files is the intersection of matches and includes, *minus* the excludes; e.g., `(M /\ I) - E`.  Multiple matches/includes/excludes are unioned together.

So for example, the example above matches `some_path/included` but not `included` (because `some_path` doesn't match against this path). However, if you wrote `-Isome_path -I.*included` instead, then `some_path` would be included (because the include set unioned these two together.)  The net effect is that you can use `--include` to filter out matches that don't match *any* of the include patterns.

Mercurial special cases the situation when there are no matches (that means match everything) and when there are no includes or excludes (include everything, exclude nothing).